# Use DisplayFormatAttribute with Kendo NumericTextBox

Tags: asp.net, kendo-ui, asp.net-mvc-5, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendonumerictextbox

I have model with `DisplayFormat` attribute

```
public class MyModel
{
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:N2}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public decimal? Amount { get; set; }
}
```

In View i have

```
@(Html.Kendo().NumericTextBoxFor(m=> m.Amount ))
```

However that does not format the value in numeric text box.

If i change the view as

```
@(Html.Kendo().NumericTextBoxFor(m=> m.Amount).Format("N2"))
```

then it works.

However using `Format` in razor view is undesirable. I would like to handle formatting using data annotation attributes.

How can i use `DisplayFormat` attribute with Kendo MVC NumericTextBox control?

**Note**
Based on [telerik's forum](http://www.telerik.com/forums/use-displayformatattribute-with-numerictextbox) post on `02 Oct 2014`

> After further consideration we decoded tp add a support for
>   DataFormatString in the next official release of Kendo UI scheduled
>   for the mid of next week. You can downloaded it once it is out and
>   give it a try.

The version i'm using is `v2016.3.1118` but it seems it still not working

Answer (score 0):

I have prepared some tests on 2017.3.1026 version. Works perfectly for your example. Looks like your version still have problem with **DataFormatString**. Update should resolve your issue.